# Voltage amplifier analyze

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier

Could anyone help to analyze the circuit?
I think block A should be a OP comparator.
How about the other blocks function?
Thanks a lot!
The V1 is a adjust voltage source from a DAC between 4V to -4V

[image]

Comment: Is that Bob Pease's handwriting?

Comment: Yes - I had the same impression.

Answer (score 0):

A: the input stage. R9/R10 determines the gain. the inverting input pin of the opamp is the non-inverting input pin of the composite amplifier.

B: meant to be a common gate amplifier but I don't think it works. the designer might have meant to use it as a current transmitter, for speed likely.

C: common source amplifier.

D: a CCS.

edit: I think Q1 is a p-ch mosfet. if so, B is to isolate the opamp from the high rail voltages (negative rail here). so that you don't need a high voltage opamp in A.

> The V1 is a adjust voltage source from a DAC between 4V to -4V

the output would be 20x (21x more precisely) of that, so 160v swing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i forget to say that V1 is a voltage output from a DAC, +4V to -4V. What is R2 function in block A? In block D, how the Q3 act as CCS?

Comment: B looks like a plausible (P type) common gate amp to me, what do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: I think you are right on that. if it were a n-ch, it would have needed a dc path to the positive rail, which it doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a class A amplifier because circuit D is acting as a constant current source to the MOSFET (Q2) drain in circuit C. Q3 is circuit D is the current source and with 10 volts on the gate and 4k7 on the source, there will be between 1 and 2 mA flowing.

Q1 and Q2 are a cascoded (not cascaded) common-gate amplifier (circuits B and C).

Circuit A sets the overall voltage gain at 21 if R9 is 5 k (a bit of a scrawl). R2 sets the input impedance to the overall circuit at 10 k ohms.

Comment: I think Q3 gate should have 140V, is that right?

Comment: Could you please help to explain how Q3 act as currentsource? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused you. It is 140 volts but I was thinking ahead and referring to the gate voltage with respect to the top rail. It's that ten volts (due to the zener) that sets the current through the 4.7 kohm resistor.

Comment: Try googling mosfet current source and almost certainly the images you get will be for an N channel device. Understand how that works then you have to think in upsidedown mode for the P channel fet in your diagram.